Tyring to connect my backend with mongoDB
I'm trying to connect backend with mongo_db , but i got this error again and again
"Error connecting to MongoDB MongoServerError: bad auth : authentication failed"
I've tried following

checked my credentials
checked Network Acess ( set my Ip and also acess anywhere ip 0.0.0./0 which includes also my ip)
created new cluster for several times but got the same error
this is my string MONGO_URL=mongodb+srv://name:password@cluster0.nwkvlx3.mongodb.net/Cluster0?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0
I'm hiding my credentials. my db_name is "Cluster0".


Try to add authSource=admin at the connection string, i.e. mongodb+srv://name:password@cluster0.nwkvlx3.mongodb.net/Cluster0?authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority

thanks for reply, I tried adding " authSource=admin"  but getting the same error :(

Then I would guess a typo in your username or password.

Does your password contain special characters. See here if it does.

it worked ,there was a type , I forgot to give cluster name. thank you buddy.
